# Difference between this two sentences

Tags: passive-voice, tough-movement

I was reading an academic paper, and this sentence came up:

*This matrix is not easy to be estimated exactly*

Why the author has chosen this form, in some sense convoluted because it contains three verbs and didn't go for something as:

*It is not easy to estimate this matrix exactly*

Is there any major difference between these two?

Comment: Why didn’t you say, “I read this sentence in an academic paper.”  It’s a simple sentence instead of a complex one and has only one verb instead of two (including a phrasal verb).

Comment: So you are saying that the major difference between the two sentences is just style? I am sorry English is not my native language; I thought I was losing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is deeper than it may seem to many native speakers. It would have been difficult for a non-native speaker to uncover the key concept of *tough movement* (see brief excerpt below). I therefore answer your question.

The adjective *easy* applies logically to the estimating of the matrix and not to the matrix.

The author has wrongly applied *easy* to the matrix and not to the estimation. They have mistakenly used a construction that parallels “It is not easy to be cured of tuberculosis”, “... to be fitted with a false leg”,”... to be rescued from an avalanche”, where the verb creates a reaction in the subject. There is no reaction in a matrix.

Your own version correctly applies the adjective *easy* to the estimation. It does so by using the grammatical concept of:

> *Tough movement* = In formal syntax, tough movement refers to sentences in which the syntactic subject of the main verb is logically the object of an embedded non-finite verb. The following sentences illustrate tough movement.
>
> (1) This problem is tough to solve.
>
> (2) Chris is easy to please.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tough_movement)

The link contains extensive further discussion of the concept, too lengthy and formal to repeat here.